# python list in a list problem...moving elements that have certain values in certain indices to a new list creates empty lists if it doesn't match

Tags: python, list

I am creating an rpg and I ran into this interesting problem.  Some background:

I have a list of lists that have "bosses" in them.  Based on how many battles the player has been in, I only want certain difficulties of bosses to be available , so I set up the logic to sort the bosses out and place them in a new list.  Basically, the logic works, and will sort the bosses list and seed a new list, but for the bosses that do not match, it adds an empty list in the place that the boss was located on the original list.  What am I doing wrong, and what might be some solutions that will either avoid the empty lists altogether, or remove them once they get added to the new list?

This is just an example of the list (too much data to paste the original):

```
unplayed_scenarios= [
    ["boss 1", "Easy"],
    ["boss 2", "Hard"],
    ["boss 3", "Medium"],
    ["boss 4", "Easy"],
       ...
    ["boss 30", "Easy"]
]
```

And this is the function:

```
scenario_count = 2
total_unplayed_scenarios = len(scenarios.unplayed_scenarios)

def choose_scenario():

    for items in scenarios.unplayed_scenarios:
        if scenario_count <= 3:
            new_list = []
            if items[1] == "Super Easy":
                new_list.append(items)
            if items[1] == "Easy":
                new_list.append(items)
            print(new_list)


        if scenario_count > 3 and  scenario_count < 6:
            new_list = []
            if items[1] == "Super Easy":
                new_list.extend(items)
            if items[1] == "Easy":
                new_list.extend(items)
            if items[1] == "Medium":
                new_list.extend(items)
            print(new_list)

        if scenario_count > 6 and  scenario_count < 9:
            new_list = []
            if items[1] == "Super Easy":
                new_list.extend(items)
            if items[1] == "Easy":
                new_list.extend(items)
            if items[1] == "Medium":
                new_list.extend(items)
            if items[1] == "Hard":
                new_list.extend(items)
            print(new_list)
```

The output for when the count, for example, is set to 2 is this:
NOTE:  This is based off of my original list, and not the example that I typed at the beginning of this post.  The empty lists are where there are items that do not match my logic that I am selecting.

```
[]
[['test1', 'Super Easy']]
[]
[]
[['test4', 'Easy']]
[['test5', 'Easy']]
[]
```

Comment: I think you should put print(new_list) outside the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, all you need to do is move `new_list=[]` outside your `for` loop and remove the repeated creation of empty lists in your `if` statements.

Also you can reduce repeated `append` by using `if something in (a,b,c)`:

```
def choose_scenario():
    new_list = []
    for items in scenarios.unplayed_scenarios:
        if scenario_count <= 3:
            if items[1] in ("Super Easy", "Easy"):
                new_list.append(items)
        elif 3 < scenario_count < 6:
            if items[1] in ("Super Easy", "Easy", "Medium"):
                new_list.append(items)
        elif 6 < scenario_count < 9:
            if items[1] in ("Super Easy", "Easy", "Medium","Hard"):
                new_list.append(items)

    print(new_list)
```

Comment: should be "in" not "=="  for the two if statements

Comment: Thanks!  I am kind of a newbie, so I didnt even know about the "if items[1] in ('...')" thing.